# numpy mean with comparison operator in the parameter

Tags: python, numpy

I came across a Python code which had something similar to what follows:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
a
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
np.mean(a)
4.0
np.mean(a <=3)
0.42857142857142855
np.mean(a <=4)
0.5714285714285714
```

I don't understand what does the comparison operator signify ? Any pointers for numpy's mean() function implementation would be nice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well if you write `a <= 3`, you construct an array with values:

```
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Since `True` has value `1.0` (or `1`) and `False` has value `0.0` (or `0`), it calculates the `mean` over the list of booleans. So in other words it will here count the number of elements for which the value holds over the total number of elements.

`mean` itself has no *specific* behavior: if you feed it a list of `Foo`s, it will simply evaluate `Foo1+Foo2+...Foon` and divide it over the length of the list, and:

```
>>> False+True
1
>>> True+True
2
```

Therefore the result of `np.mean(a <=3)` is 3/7 (the first three elements are `<= 3` over seven elements) and `np.mean(a <=4)` 4/7 here.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to calculate the mean of the little numbers.

Here is the way :

```
In [2]: a=arange(8)

In [3]: b= a<=3

In [4]: b  # condition
Out[4]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [5]: a[b] #selection
Out[5]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [6]: a[b].mean()
Out[6]: 1.5
```